# How to zoom inside a number range

Tags: functions

I'm trying to create a ruler and the zooming functionality.

So let's say i have 3 numbers ranging from 0.0 to 1.0.

My 3 values in that case should be 0.0 0.5 1.0

Now i want to zoom inside this range and the zooming to be relative to the point of my cursor. (ranges from 0.0 to 1.0)

So if i put my cursor on 0.0 and zoom in the output shall be 0.0 0.25 0.5

my cursor on 0.5 and zoom in 0.25 0.5 0.75

my cursor on 1.0 and zoom in 0.5 0.75 1.0

So i need a function that combines the minimum value (0.0), the maximum (1.0) the cursor position (i.e. 0.5) and the zoom amount ( i.e. * 2.0f )

Can someone give me some direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several possibilities.  Here is one:

Suppose the range you can see is $[m, M]$ with a centre point of $\frac{m+M}{2}$, and you zoom in on $P$  where $0 \le m \le P \le  M \le 1$

then you could get the new range $\left[\frac{m+P}{2},\frac{P+M}{2}\right]$ with a centre point  $\frac{m+2P+M}{4}$

Generalising this, with a zoom factor of $z$ rather than $2$, you could go to a new range of $\left[\frac{m+(z-1)P}{z},\frac{(z-1)P+M}{z}\right]$ and a new centre point of  $\frac{m+2(z-1)P+M}{2z}$.

Comment: Brilliant it works, thank you

Answer (score 0):

We will use a zoom factor of $z$ each time. So if you initially have a range of $[a,b]$ (i.e. a length of $b-a$) and you zoom in on the value $c$ then the length shown must reduced by a factor of $z$ to $\frac{b-a}{z}$. You want half of this on either side of the point you zoomed in on so your new range is:

$$\left[c-\frac{b-a}{2z},c+\frac{b-a}{2z}\right]$$